# Many to Many relationship referring to the same table

Tags: sql

I have an account table and want to link income accounts with expense accounts both of which are in the same account table.  Should I create a linking table called IncomeAccount with an account_id column and an income_account column both of which are FKs to the Account table?

Comment: This sounds reasonable..You should ask yourself how these data will be accessed and thus does your representation fit the needs?

Comment: Yep, that's how it's usually done. That new table can also have extra attributes, such as "who linked them", "when did it happen", etc.